# datatable in laravel 5.2 sometime gives error why

Tags: laravel

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IyTS.png)
But when I refresh it working fine.Please give some suggestions, why this error occures

Comment: That's not a Laravel error, that is a JavaScript alert with text Error

Comment: Could you give us the code that is run when encountering this error? Can't see what's wrong from a screenshot showing an alert.

Comment: Please copy & paste the error message in your post, don't link to images. Include the relevant source code and the inputs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have null or undefined values in your data, it will show you an error, but not an alert with juste "error" as string.

You must have an alert('error') somewhere in your code. Check it and show us your code.

Comment: function getListing()
{
 var jsonData = ""
 $.ajax({type:"GET", url: site_url+'/doc/listing',
 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
 dataType:"json",
 async:false,
 success: function(data)
 {loadDataTable(data)},
 error: function(data)
 {alert('error')}})};

Comment: loadDataTable function is here
function loadDataTable(data)
{
 $("table").dataTable({
  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
 "aaData": data,
 "aoColumns": [
 { "mData": "ID" },
 { "mData": "Description" },
 { "mData": "Date"},
 { "mData": "Status",
  'mRender': function (data, type, full) {
    if (full.TMStatus == '1') 
    return 'Active';
    else 
    return 'In-Active';
    }
  },   
 ]
});


}